# Zahler, Sussman, and Kolata Controversy of 1977

Tags: physics-social-history

In Steven Strogatz's "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos: With Applications to Physics, Biology, Chemistry, and Engineering", Storgatz mentions a "violent controversy" between Zahler, Sussman, and Kolata that happened in 1977. However, I am not able to find anything like that. What was the controversy he is talking about here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following (and the references there) seems relevant: Guckenheimer, J. The catastrophe controversy. The Mathematical Intelligencer 1, 15–20 (1978).

Looks like it was about attempts to hype the catastrophe theory and extend it to numerous areas where its usefulness was dubious.